# Formatting text in Adb Shell

Tags: grep, adb

I was doing some `adb shell` stuff on windows and stuck at a point. Here's what I was doing..
I was printing all installed apps on my phone and getting their exact path.

```
zeroltetmo:/ # pm list packages -f 
package:/system/app/FilterProvider/FilterProvider.apk=com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider
package:/system/priv-app/CtsShimPrivPrebuilt/CtsShimPrivPrebuilt.apk=com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
package:/system/app/YouTube/Youtube.apk=com.google.android.youtube
package:/system/app/vsimservice/vsimservice.apk=com.sec.vsimservice
package:/system/priv-app/WallpaperCropper/WallpaperCropper.apk=com.android.wallpapercropper
package:/system/framework/framework-res.apk=android
package:/system/framework/samsung-framework-res/samsung-framework-res.apk=com.samsung.android.framework.res
package:/data/app/com.whatsapp-1/base.apk=com.whatsapp
package:/data/app/ru.meefik.busybox-2/base.apk=ru.meefik.busybox
package:/data/app/com.google.android.play.games-1/base.apk=com.google.android.play.games
```

But,
I want this to print only `system/app` directory but only upto `folder` name instead of the full path. What i'm doing is piping this to `grep` and using this pattern to get the result.

```
zeroltetmo:/ # pm list packages -f | grep -o "system/app.*\/"
system/app/FilterProvider/
system/app/RootPA/
system/app/YouTube/
system/app/ClipboardSaveService/
system/app/TetheringAutomation/
system/app/GoogleExtShared/
system/app/WfdBroker/
system/app/vsimservice/
system/app/USBSettings/
system/app/EasyOneHand3/
```

But the problem is this **/** at the end of folder name that I'm stuck with.

Comment: in your sample output, you only have one directory level below `app`, so you could also do `grep -o 'system/app/[^/]*'`

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for your help, it worked. Also can u please explain this pattern.

Comment: `system/app/` matches these characters literally... `[^/]*` matches all non `/` characters..  see [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for more details on character classes.. if you need a tutorial, see [my github repo](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/gnu_grep.md) for example based introduction to grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the trailing slashes out with `sed` like that:

```
pm list packages -f | grep -o "system/app.*/" | sed 's,/$,,'
```

Explanation of the `sed` command:

`s` stands for [substitution](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-1)

`,` delimits command name from its arguments - it's easier to use something different `/` when we want to replace `/`

`/$` - string to be replaced. In this case it means slash at the end of the line

The string to replace `/$` with is empty because we want to remove it.

Comment: Great, it worked. Can u please explain what this `sed` pattern is doing exactly.

Comment: @Mujtaba: I explained it.